# Group by two colums that match when altered

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table in database named Message and this is how the table looks like:

[image: Message table]

I need to find the last message of conversation gomez had with every user from the table. So, I want to make a column that combines sender and receiver username and group by with that column. However, how do i validate

> Lucy+Gomez == Gomez+Lucy

My code so far:

```
SELECT sender+receiver, content, dateSent
FROM MESSAGE
WHERE sender = 'Gomez' OR receiver = 'Gomez'
GROUP BY sender+receiver 
ORDER BY dateSent desc;
```

Comment: Somewhat unclear what your expected query result set is given `content` in the select list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM MESSAGE m1
WHERE 'Gomez' IN (m1.sender, m1.receiver) 
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM MESSAGE m2
  WHERE (m1.sender, m1.receiver) IN ((m2.sender, m2.receiver), (m2.receiver, m2.sender))
    AND m2.dateSent > m1.dateSent
) 
ORDER BY m1.dateSent DESC;
```

Or, if your version of MySql is 8.0+, use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT sender, receiver, content, dateSent
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
              PARTITION BY LEAST(sender, receiver), GREATEST(sender, receiver) 
              ORDER BY dateSent DESC
            ) rn
  FROM MESSAGE
  WHERE 'Gomez' IN (sender, receiver)
) m
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY dateSent DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=999f1d4580cfbb1b95e9177d5389cdc8).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your original concatenation approach, consider always concatenating in alphabetical order:

```
SELECT 
  case 
    when sender < receiver 
    then concat(sender, receiver) 
    else concat(receiver, sender) 
  end,
  dateSent
FROM MESSAGE
WHERE sender = 'Gomez' OR receiver = 'Gomez'
GROUP BY case when sender < receiver then concat(sender, receiver) else concat(receiver, sender) end
ORDER BY dateSent desc;
```

Which can be easily modified further if the sender/receiver values need to be treated in a case-insensitive manner.